# Availability of alcohol in Morocco?

Tags: shopping, alcohol, morocco

Can we count on buying some alcohol in Morocco, particularly in Fes?

I don't mean drinks in a bar but a bottle of wine or better whiskey or something like that in some supermarket and how much it is in comparison with Europe?

Comment: Don't know about the prices, but local beer and wine should be relatively cheap; and major supermarkets (carrefour) should have international brands available.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, alcohol is available in some Supermarkets and stores in major cities, like Fes, and only small stores in some mid size cities.

Some “major" Supermarket like Marjane don't sell alcohol anymore, Carrefour, Assima are amongst the exceptions, but may be hard to get to if you don't have a car.

There are a few small liquor sellers in the city, just ask around ( but they are 10-30% more expensive than a supermarket and have limited choices).....

The Price is about 2-3 times that of Europe due to "luxury" taxes, most local alcohol is overpriced given it's quality and is priced not far from imports. ..

So no cheap booze if that was the object of the Q.